# PHP submit query not working,

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a very extensive and large web form that users can submit to a PostGreSQL database of mine. I'm having trouble completing the functionality though. I have smaller web forms that this works a treat with but I'm getting an error - `Query failed: ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions`

Now, of course, I can interpret what this means but I've looked through the file time and time again and cannot see anything wrong with the web form at all. Could I get a few more pairs of eyes on the web form itself and the PHP submit query. I'm also looking for advice on how to make the PHP script smaller, seems a very unprofessional way that I am carrying out the functionality. Can any of you identify which column/variable is out of place.

**Web form.html**

```
<form name="availability" method="post" action="auth/avaisubmit.php">
<h5>7.1 Orientation</h5> 
<label>Are floor-plans or maps available?</label>
<select name="floorplans">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br /> 

<label>Specify what formats</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="format_specify"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are videos with British Sign Language(BSL) available?</label>
<select name="videos_bsl">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Do you highlight what ISN'T accessible?</label>
<select name="highlight_not_accessible">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Not applicable">Not applicable</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Do staff offer a browsing collections service? (i.e. where staff can browse collections and retrieve items for disabled visitors?</label>
<select name="browsing_service">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>If yes, please add more details(for example if it needs to be pre-booked).</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="more_details"></textarea> <br />

<h5> 7.2 Alternative Formats </h5>
<label>Is an audio system available?</label>
<select name="audio_system">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />
<!--ADD COLUMNS BACK INTO TYPESCRIPT-->

<label>What type of audio system is it?</label>
    <input type="text" name="audio_system_type" /> <br />

<label>Where is the audio system available?</label>
    <input type="text" name="where_audio" /> <br />

<label>Is there a text version? </label>
<select name="text_version">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Text version - Description </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="text_version_description"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are verbal descriptions<sup>*1</sup> available?</label>
<select name="verbal">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Verbal description - Description</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="verbal_description"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are Tactile<sup>*2</sup> models available?</label>
<select name="tactile">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>  
</select> <br /> <br /> 

<label>Tactile models - Description</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="tactile_description"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are replicas<sup>*3</sup> available? (including digital copies of documents)</label>
<select name="replicas">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Replicas - Description</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="replicas_description"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are DAISY (digital talking books)<sup>*4</sup> available?</label>
<select name="daisy">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>DAISY - Description</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="daisy_description"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are CDs<sup>*5</sup> available?</label>
<select name="cd">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> CDs - Description </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="cd_description"></textarea> <br />

<label> Are DVDs<sup>*6</sup> available? </label>
<select name="dvd">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> DVDs - Description </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="dvd_description"></textarea> <br />

<label> Are raised images<sup>*7</sup> available?</label>
<select name="raised_images">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> Raised images - Description </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="raised_images_description"></textarea> <br />

<label> Is tape available</label>
<select name="tape">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> Tape - Description </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="tape_description"></textarea> <br />

<label>Please list any other formats have, e.g. MP3 etc</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="other_formats"></textarea> <br />

<label>Is a format conversion service<sup>*8</sup> available?</label>
<select name="format_conversion">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> Format conversion service - Description </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="format_conversion_description"></textarea> <br />

<h5> 7.3 ICT </h5>

<label>Do you have Kiosks/interactives?</label>
<select name="kiosks">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>How many Kiosks do you have?</label>
    <input type="text" name="num_kiosks" /> <br />

<label> How are Kiosks/interactives accessible to disabled visitors?</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="accessible_kiosks"></textarea> <br />

<label> Where are the Kiosks/interactives located?</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="location_kiosks"></textarea> <br />

<label>What senses do they stimulate?</label>
<select name="senses">
    <option value="Hearing">Hearing</option>
    <option value="Sight">Sight</option>
    <option value="Touch">Touch</option>
    <option value="Smell">Smell</option>
    <option value-"Taste">Taste</option>
</select> <br /> <br /> 

<label> Are there videos with captions and audio descriptions?</label>
<select name="videos_captions_audios">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> How many captioned or described videos are available?</label>
    <input type="text" name="num_captioned_videos" /> <br />

<label> Where are the captioned or described videos located? </label>
    <input type="text" name="location_captioned_videos" /> <br /> 

<label>Are there fixed point or portable audio guides or interpretation?</label>
<select name="audio_guides">
    <option name="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option name="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br /> 

<label>How many of these are available?</label>
    <input type="text" name="num_audio_guides" /> <br />

<label>Where are they located?</label>
    <input type="text" name="location_audio_guides" /> <br />

<label>Are transcripts of audio/video available?</label>
<select name="transcripts">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>How many of these are available?</label>
    <input type="text" name="num_transcripts" /> <br />

<label> Please give details </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="details_transcripts"></textarea> <br />

<label>Do visitors/users have access to ICT equipment as part of their visit?</label>
<select name="access_ict">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Are there height-adjustable tables and chairs?</label>
<select name="tables_chairs">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option> 
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>What size is the screen?</label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="screen_size"></textarea> <br />

<label>Are there monitors mounted on universal arms for viewing at any angle?</label>
<select name="monitor_universal">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Is there a selection of mice, ketboards and joysticks with wired and wireless connection?</label>
<select name="mice_keyboards_joysticks">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Are there standalone text to speech machines?<sup>*9</sup> </label>
<select name="text_to_speech">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label> Description - Text to speech machines</label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="text_to_speech_description"> </textarea> <br />

<label>Is there closed circuit TV magnification equipment with X-Y tables?*</label>
<select name="closed_circuit_tv">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Is there an accessible Website?</label>
<select name="website">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Tested by:</label> <input type="text" name="accessible_website_tester" /> <br />

<label>Have you carried out access testing with disabled website users?</label>
<select name="access_testing">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Tested by:</label> <input type="text" name="accessible_testing_tester" /> <br />

<label>Can you easily increase font size?</label>
<select name="font_size">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No<option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Are pictures and text described?</label>
<select name="pictures_text_described">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Does this include downloadable resources in alternative formats?</label>
<select name="downloadables">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Downloadbles - Description</label> <input type="text" name="downloadables_description" /> <br />

<label>Is there website available on-site?</label>
<select name="website_onsite">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Where:</label> <input type="text" name="website_where" /> <br />

<label>Do you provide automatic page turners?</label>   
<select name="auto_page_turners">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>Add any other assistive technologies that you use to increase access</label> <input type="text" name="other_technologies" /> <br />

<label>Do you offer different assistive technologies?</label>
<select name="other_different">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select> <br /> <br />

<label>If yes, please list some examples<sup>*10</sup> </label>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="other_different_examples"></textarea> <br />

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Save"> <br />
</form>
```

**PHP Submit.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_NAME']))
{
    $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'];
}
else
{       
    $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $_POST['SESS_NAME'];
}

$username = $_SESSION["SESS_NAME"];
$floorplans = $_POST["floorplans"];
$format = $_POST["format_specify"];
$videosbsl = $_POST["videos_bsl"];
$highlight = $_POST["highlight_not_accessible"];
$browsing = $_POST["browsing_service"];
$details = $_POST["more_details"];
$audio = $_POST["audio_system"];
$whereaudio = $_POST["where_audio"]; 
$textversion = $_POST["text_version"];
$textversiondesc = $_POST["text_version_description"];
$verbal = $_POST["verbal"]; 
$verbaldesc = $_POST["verbal_description"];
$tactile = $_POST["tactile"];
$tactiledesc = $_POST["tactile_description"];
$replicas = $_POST["replicas"];
$replicasdesc = $_POST["replicas_description"];
$daisy = $_POST["daisy"];
$daisydesc = $_POST["daisy_description"];
$cd = $_POST["cd"];
$cddesc = $_POST["cd_description"];
$dvd = $_POST["dvd"];
$dvddesc = $_POST["dvd_description"];
$raised = $_POST["raised_images"];
$raiseddesc = $_POST["raised_images_description"];
    $tape = $_POST["tape"];
$tapedesc = $_POST["tape_description"];
$other = $_POST["other_formats"];
$formatconv = $_POST["format_conversion"];
$fcdesc = $_POST["format_conversion_description"];
$kiosks = $_POST["kiosks"];
$numkiosks = $_POST["num_kiosks"];
$accesskiosks = $_POST["accessible_kiosks"];
$locationkiosks = $_POST["location_kiosks"];
$senses = $_POST["senses"];
    $vca = $_POST["videos_captions_audios"];
$numvca = $_POST["num_captioned_videos"];
$locvca = $_POST["location_captioned videos"];
$audioGuide = $_POST["audio_guides"];
$numAG = $_POST["num_audio_guides"];
$locAG = $_POST["location_audio_guides"];
$transcripts = $_POST["transcripts"];
$numtranscripts = $_POST["num_transcripts"];
$detailtranscripts = $_POST["details_transcripts"];
$accessICT = $_POST["access_ict"];
$tableschairs = $_POST["tables_chairs"];
$screensize = $_POST["screen_size"];
$monitors = $_POST["monitor_universal"];
$mkj = $_POST["mice_keyboards_joysticks"];  
$textspeech = $_POST["text_to_speech"];
$textspeechdesc = $_POST["text_to_speech_description"];
$circutTV = $_POST["closed_circuit_tv"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$tester = $_POST["accessible_website_tester"];
$accessTesting = $_POST["access_testing"];
$accessibleTester = $_POST["accessible_testing_tester"];
$fontsize = $_POST["font_size"];
$pictexts = $_POST["pictures_text_described"];
$downloadables = $_POST["downloadables"];
$downloadablesdesc = $_POST["downloadables_description"];
$webonsite = $_POST["website_onsite"];
$webwhere = $_POST["website_where"];
$pageturners = $_POST["auto_page_turners"];
$othertech = $_POST["other_technologies"];
$otherdiff = $_POST["other_different"];
$otherdiffeg = $_POST["other_different_examples"];  
$systemaudio = $_POST["audio_system_type"];

$conn = pg_connect("db_string");

$user = pg_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE username='$username'");
$user_row = pg_fetch_assoc($user);
$user_res = $user_row['s_id'];
var_dump($user_res);
$check = pg_query("SELECT name FROM availability");
$num_rows = pg_num_rows($check);

if($num_rows == 1) 
{
    $res = pg_query("UPDATE availability SET (floorplans_maps, formats, videos_with_bsl, highlight_not_accessible, browsing_collection_service,
                                              more_detail, audio_system, where_audio_system, text_version, text_version_description, verbal, verbal_description,
                                              tactile_models, tactile_models_description, replicas, replicas_description, daisy, daisy_description, cd, cd_description, dvd, dvd_description, raised_images, raised_images_descriptipon, tape, tape_description,
                                              other_formats, format_conversion, format_conversion_description, kiosks, num_kiosks, accessible_kiosks, location_kiosks, senses,
                                              video_captions_audio_description, num_captioned_videos, location_captioned_videos, audio_guides, num_audio_guides, location_audio_guides,
                                              transcripts, num_transcripts, details_transcripts, access_to_ict, height_adjust_chairs, screen_size, monitor_universal_arms, mice_keyboards_joysticks,
                                              text_to_speech_machines, text_to_speech_machines_description, closed_circuit_tv, accessible_website, accessible_website_tester, access_testing, access_testing_tester,
                                              font_size_adjustment, pictures_text_described, downloadables_included, downloadables_description, website_onsite, website_where, auto_page_turner, other_technologies,
                                              offer_different, offer_different_examples, type_audio_system) = 
                                              ('$floorplans',
                                              '$format',
                                              '$videosbsl',
                                              '$highlight',
                                              '$browsing',
                                              '$details',
                                              '$audio',
                                              '$whereaudio',
                                              '$textversion',
                                              '$textversiondesc',
                                              '$verbal',
                                              '$verbaldesc',
                                              '$tactile',
                                              '$tactiledesc',
                                              '$replicas',
                                              '$replicasdesc',
                                              '$daisy',
                                              '$daisydesc',
                                              '$cd',
                                              '$cddesc',
                                              '$dvd',
                                              '$dvddesc',
                                              '$raised',
                                              '$raiseddesc',
                                              '$tape',
                                              '$tapedesc',
                                              '$other',
                                              '$formatconv',
                                              '$fcdesc',
                                              '$kiosks',
                                              '$numkiosks',
                                              '$accesskiosks',
                                              '$locationkiosks',
                                              '$senses',
                                              '$vca',
                                              '$numvca',
                                              '$locvca',
                                              '$audioGuide',
                                              '$numAG',
                                              '$locAG',
                                              '$transcripts',
                                              '$numtranscripts',
                                              '$detailtranscripts',
                                              '$accessICT',
                                              '$tableschairs',
                                              '$screensize',
                                              '$monitors',
                                              '$mkj',
                                              '$textspeech',
                                              '$textspeechdesc',
                                              '$circutTV',
                                              '$website',
                                              '$tester',
                                              '$accessTesting',
                                              '$accessibleTester',
                                              '$fontsize',
                                              '$pictexts',
                                              '$downloadables',
                                              '$downloadablesdesc'
                                              '$webonsite',
                                              '$webwhere',
                                              '$pageturners',
                                              '$othertech',
                                              '$otherdiff',
                                              '$otherdiffeg',
                                              '$systemaudio') WHERE name='$user_res'");
}
elseif($num_rows == 0)
{
    $res = pg_query("INSERT INTO availability (floorplans_maps, formats, videos_with_bsl, highlight_not_accessible, browsing_collection_service,
                                              more_detail, audio_system, where_audio_system, text_version, text_version_description, verbal, verbal_description,
                                              tactile_models, tactile_models_description, replicas, replicas_description, daisy, daisy_description, cd, cd_description, dvd, dvd_description, raised_images, raised_images_descriptipon, tape, tape_description,
                                              other_formats, format_conversion, format_conversion_description, kiosks, num_kiosks, accessible_kiosks, location_kiosks, senses,
                                              video_captions_audio_description, num_captioned_videos, location_captioned_videos, audio_guides, num_audio_guides, location_audio_guides,
                                              transcripts, num_transcripts, details_transcripts, access_to_ict, height_adjust_chairs, screen_size, monitor_universal_arms, mice_keyboards_joysticks,
                                              text_to_speech_machines, text_to_speech_machines_description, closed_circuit_tv, accessible_website, accessible_website_tester, access_testing, access_testing_tester,
                                              font_size_adjustment, pictures_text_described, downloadables_included, downloadables_description, website_onsite, website_where, auto_page_turner, other_technologies,
                                              offer_different, offer_different_examples, name, type_audio_system) VALUES (
                                              '$floorplans',
                                              '$format',
                                              '$videosbsl',
                                              '$highlight',
                                              '$browsing',
                                              '$details',
                                              '$audio',
                                              '$whereaudio',
                                              '$textversion',
                                              '$textversiondesc',
                                              '$verbal',
                                              '$verbaldesc',
                                              '$tactile',
                                              '$tactiledesc',
                                              '$replicas',
                                              '$replicasdesc',
                                              '$daisy',
                                              '$daisydesc',
                                              '$cd',
                                              '$cddesc',
                                              '$dvd',
                                              '$dvddesc',
                                              '$raised',
                                              '$raiseddesc',
                                              '$tape',
                                              '$tapedesc',
                                              '$other',
                                              '$formatconv',
                                              '$fcdesc',
                                              '$kiosks',
                                              '$numkiosks',
                                              '$accesskiosks',
                                              '$locationkiosks',
                                              '$senses',
                                              '$vca',
                                              '$numvca',
                                              '$locvca',
                                              '$audioGuide',
                                              '$numAG',
                                              '$locAG',
                                              '$transcripts',
                                              '$numtranscripts',
                                              '$detailtranscripts',
                                              '$accessICT',
                                              '$tableschairs',
                                              '$screensize',
                                              '$monitors',
                                              '$mkj',
                                              '$textspeech',
                                              '$textspeechdesc',
                                              '$circutTV',
                                              '$website',
                                              '$tester',
                                              '$accessTesting',
                                              '$accessibleTester',
                                              '$fontsize',
                                              '$pictexts',
                                              '$downloadables',
                                              '$downloadablesdesc'
                                              '$webonsite',
                                              '$webwhere',
                                              '$pageturners',
                                              '$othertech',
                                              '$otherdiff',
                                              '$otherdiffeg',
                                              '$user_res',
                                              '$systemaudio')");
}

pg_close($conn);
```

?>

Again huge apologies for how long the source code is. Just can't seem to figure out the error.

Comment: Apparently your INSERT has more target columns then expressions. I'd say count and compare!

Comment: Use a loop to get the data's in the variable and check if they are really exist there using isset function. Double check if you are passing the right number of column name and there value accordingly. That seams the problem. Again , use a loop DanielD

Comment: You've specified 66 fields to set:
`floorplans_maps, formats,...etc etc`
but only 65 values to go in them:
`'$floorplans','$format',....etc etc`

Comment: You are really opening up for sql injections here, since you are accepting the _POST values and inserting them directly in the sql. This is a major security risk, and should be avoided even on none-public projects. Sanitize your values or to the right thing and use binded parameters.

Comment: @SvenTore is there a way I can `pg_escape_string` the array of variables. I know this prevents SQL injections but just wondering if there is a way to do without doing it 66 times?

Comment: @DanielD if you are asking if you can logically skip it. Then no. But if you just don't want to write all the code you could make an array of all the values to look for in the post. Loop trough them and add them to the sql query after sanitizing them. If your post-variable-names and sql-table names does not match then use a key-value array as mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's occurring because you've missed a comma after the '$downloadablesdesc' entry in **both** queries.

Consequently, the counts don't match up:

```
'$downloadables',
'$downloadablesdesc' <-- should be a comma here
'$webonsite',
```

You can confirm this using the JSfiddle I built to check:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpAm/Z7KzA/1/

Paste these (your columns) into the box on the left:

```
floorplans_maps, formats, videos_with_bsl, highlight_not_accessible, browsing_collection_service,more_detail, audio_system, where_audio_system, text_version, text_version_description, verbal, verbal_description,tactile_models, tactile_models_description, replicas, replicas_description, daisy, daisy_description, cd, cd_description, dvd, dvd_description, raised_images, raised_images_descriptipon, tape, tape_description,other_formats, format_conversion, format_conversion_description, kiosks, num_kiosks, accessible_kiosks, location_kiosks, senses,video_captions_audio_description, num_captioned_videos, location_captioned_videos, audio_guides, num_audio_guides, location_audio_guides,transcripts, num_transcripts, details_transcripts, access_to_ict, height_adjust_chairs, screen_size, monitor_universal_arms, mice_keyboards_joysticks,text_to_speech_machines, text_to_speech_machines_description, closed_circuit_tv, accessible_website, accessible_website_tester, access_testing, access_testing_tester,font_size_adjustment, pictures_text_described, downloadables_included, downloadables_description, website_onsite, website_where, auto_page_turner, other_technologies,offer_different, offer_different_examples, type_audio_system
```

And these (your values) into the box on the right, and click the button:

```
'$floorplans',
                                              '$format',
                                              '$videosbsl',
                                              '$highlight',
                                              '$browsing',
                                              '$details',
                                              '$audio',
                                              '$whereaudio',
                                              '$textversion',
                                              '$textversiondesc',
                                              '$verbal',
                                              '$verbaldesc',
                                              '$tactile',
                                              '$tactiledesc',
                                              '$replicas',
                                              '$replicasdesc',
                                              '$daisy',
                                              '$daisydesc',
                                              '$cd',
                                              '$cddesc',
                                              '$dvd',
                                              '$dvddesc',
                                              '$raised',
                                              '$raiseddesc',
                                              '$tape',
                                              '$tapedesc',
                                              '$other',
                                              '$formatconv',
                                              '$fcdesc',
                                              '$kiosks',
                                              '$numkiosks',
                                              '$accesskiosks',
                                              '$locationkiosks',
                                              '$senses',
                                              '$vca',
                                              '$numvca',
                                              '$locvca',
                                              '$audioGuide',
                                              '$numAG',
                                              '$locAG',
                                              '$transcripts',
                                              '$numtranscripts',
                                              '$detailtranscripts',
                                              '$accessICT',
                                              '$tableschairs',
                                              '$screensize',
                                              '$monitors',
                                              '$mkj',
                                              '$textspeech',
                                              '$textspeechdesc',
                                              '$circutTV',
                                              '$website',
                                              '$tester',
                                              '$accessTesting',
                                              '$accessibleTester',
                                              '$fontsize',
                                              '$pictexts',
                                              '$downloadables',
                                              '$downloadablesdesc'
                                              '$webonsite',
                                              '$webwhere',
                                              '$pageturners',
                                              '$othertech',
                                              '$otherdiff',
                                              '$otherdiffeg',
                                              '$systemaudio'
```

This is the outcome:

```
floorplans_maps -- '$floorplans'
formats -- '$format'
videos_with_bsl -- '$videosbsl'
highlight_not_accessible -- '$highlight'
browsing_collection_service -- '$browsing'
more_detail -- '$details'
audio_system -- '$audio'
where_audio_system -- '$whereaudio'
text_version -- '$textversion'
text_version_description -- '$textversiondesc'
verbal -- '$verbal'
verbal_description -- '$verbaldesc'
tactile_models -- '$tactile'
tactile_models_description -- '$tactiledesc'
replicas -- '$replicas'
replicas_description -- '$replicasdesc'
daisy -- '$daisy'
daisy_description -- '$daisydesc'
cd -- '$cd'
cd_description -- '$cddesc'
dvd -- '$dvd'
dvd_description -- '$dvddesc'
raised_images -- '$raised'
raised_images_descriptipon -- '$raiseddesc'
tape -- '$tape'
tape_description -- '$tapedesc'
other_formats -- '$other'
format_conversion -- '$formatconv'
format_conversion_description -- '$fcdesc'
kiosks -- '$kiosks'
num_kiosks -- '$numkiosks'
accessible_kiosks -- '$accesskiosks'
location_kiosks -- '$locationkiosks'
senses -- '$senses'
video_captions_audio_description -- '$vca'
num_captioned_videos -- '$numvca'
location_captioned_videos -- '$locvca'
audio_guides -- '$audioGuide'
num_audio_guides -- '$numAG'
location_audio_guides -- '$locAG'
transcripts -- '$transcripts'
num_transcripts -- '$numtranscripts'
details_transcripts -- '$detailtranscripts'
access_to_ict -- '$accessICT'
height_adjust_chairs -- '$tableschairs'
screen_size -- '$screensize'
monitor_universal_arms -- '$monitors'
mice_keyboards_joysticks -- '$mkj'
text_to_speech_machines -- '$textspeech'
text_to_speech_machines_description -- '$textspeechdesc'
closed_circuit_tv -- '$circutTV'
accessible_website -- '$website'
accessible_website_tester -- '$tester'
access_testing -- '$accessTesting'
access_testing_tester -- '$accessibleTester'
font_size_adjustment -- '$fontsize'
pictures_text_described -- '$pictexts'
downloadables_included -- '$downloadables'
downloadables_description -- '$downloadablesdesc' '$webonsite'
website_onsite -- '$webwhere'
website_where -- '$pageturners'
auto_page_turner -- '$othertech'
other_technologies -- '$otherdiff'
offer_different -- '$otherdiffeg'
offer_different_examples -- '$systemaudio'
type_audio_system -- undefined
```

Comment: Smashing mate cheers. All I needed was a fresh pair of eyes. +1 cheers :)